# How to have Eclipse use JDK8 to compile a project?

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8

I'm experimenting with the new jdk8 what is available here http://jdk8.java.net/lambda/

I'm able to compile and run my project from command line.

I'm also able to add this new JDK to `Installed JREs` in Eclipse.
However, I'm not able to have Eclipse to compile and run the project with this JDK.

I'm trying to change the settings on `Project Properties/Java Compiler` but the `Use [JDK] compliance from execution environment on the 'Java Build Path'` checkbox is disabled and no matter whatever I click on this page, I cannot make it work.

I have Eclipse Platform Version: 3.7.1

Any ideas?

thx

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Eclipse uses a built-in compiler rather than `javac`. The built-in compiler obviously doesn't support Java 8 yet.

You can define a custom builder for your project which will call your `javac`. In the project's preferences, go to "Builders", add a new custom builder (which can be either an Ant script or an executable program) and disable the default built-in Java builder.

Afterwards, *running* the project with the JDK of your choice shouldn't be a problem - adding it to the "Installed JREs" preference page (as you did) should be sufficient.

Comment: [This post](http://tuhrig.de/?p=921) explains pretty well how to do it. Note that you will probably need to adjust the `javac` path arguments.

Comment: Care to update now that the landscape has changed both for Eclipse and Java?

Comment: what if your eclipse can't start up?

Answer (score 11):

Eclipse now supports JDK 8 EA:

> The Eclipse JDT/Core team is pleased to announce the availability of early access builds 
>   with support enabled for the following Java 8 features.
>
> We recommend that you start with a clean install of
>
> - Either 4.3.1 or 4.4 M2 SDK
> - Update the JDT/Core, JDT/UI bundles from  http://dist.springsource.com/snapshot/TOOLS/java8/e43
>
> This update site is set up to periodically rebuild and package the relevant projects from the top of the BETA_JAVA8 development branch.

Source: http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/eclipse-dev/msg09679.html

---

**EDIT:**

After upgrading eclipse, you need to change the JDK and the compiler level. Here is a screenshot of using lambda within Eclipse:

[image]

Comment: Oops, it seems that `sorted()` doesn't work well with `parallelStream()`.

Comment: Well, it turns out that I need to use `forEachOrdered()` instead of `forEach()`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529982/java-8-parallelstream-with-sorted

Answer (score 5):

go window->preferences->Java->Installed JREs->execution environment->Java SE-1.8

Answer (score 3):

I did it this way:

1.Right click on JRE System Library on Package Explorer and select Properties (On your right side)

[image: Right click on JRE System Library on Package Explorer and select Properties (On your right side)]

2. Change your execution environment.

[image: Change your execution environment]

Answer (score 2):

You can pretty much forget about that, as even the [plan for eclipse 3.8](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/core/r3.8/plan.php) only says "Start to work on Java 8 support."

Working with the bleeding edge has its drawbacks...

Comment: Thanks! I don't accept it right now, I'm waiting if somebody could come up with a suggestion/workaround.