# How to add jdk8 in Eclipse Indigo

Tags: java, java-8

I just read [How to have Eclipse use JDK8 to compile a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122843/how-to-have-eclipse-use-jdk8-to-compile-a-project)

What i added jdk8 to eclipse as,
[image]

From the answers of [How to have Eclipse use JDK8 to compile a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122843/how-to-have-eclipse-use-jdk8-to-compile-a-project)

I tried to Update the JDT/Core, JDT/UI bundles from http://dist.springsource.com/snapshot/TOOLS/java8/e43

But it shows error as,

```
"Eclipse Java Development Tools Patch for Java 8 Support (BETA)" is not applicable to the current configuration and will not be installed.
"Eclipse Plug-in Development Environment Patch for Java 8 Support (BETA)" is not applicable to the current configuration and will not be installed.
```

[image]

How Can i fix it ?

Comment: Does it have to be Indigo? Maybe try Luna which has build in support for Java 8, or check [this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/Eclipse_Java_8_Support_For_Kepler) for Kepler.

Comment: I suspect that it is because Kepler is newer than Indigo, so it may have some additional functionality which is required by Java 8 tools and which Indigo might not have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can say that Java 1.8 does in fact work with Eclipse Luna ( [the beta version released around March 17, 2014)](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/index.html) or later.  I tried it and it was good.

Also, I noticed that in the Eclipse Marketplace, there are now plugins to install functionality into Kepler to support JDK1.8.  I haven't tried the plugin myself though.

Comment: Can U PlZ Share the link that U downloaded Eclipse Luna.. :)

Comment: Ok, I added the link.

Answer (score 1):

This is a old topic but I just wanted to point out that I have searched enough to find that Indigo version can't be updated to S.E 1.8  here the link which is given on eclipse website to update the Execution Environment but if you try it will throw error for Indigo.

Here is the [link](http://wiki.eclipse.org/File:ExecutionEnvironmentDescriptionInstallation.png) where the Information about execution environment is given.

[This](https://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/Eclipse_Java_8_Support_For_Kepler) shows the step by step to update Execution environment.

I have tried to update Execution environment and I got the same error.

[image]