# Java configure build path

Tags: java, eclipse

I have just installed Eclipse Indigo, and created a new project. It's telling me that the build path is not configured.

I have followed `RighClick on the project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Libraries` and there I found `JRE System Library [jre1.8.0_31]` and I don't understand why it doesn't recognize it.

Any help?

Comment: What do you mean by `it doesn't recognize it`?

Comment: Have you got JDK and JRE installed, and environmental variable `JAVA_HOME` pointing to the correct location?

Comment: I haven't made any other configurations, just installed Eclipse

Comment: You can `Edit` JRE System Library and then select execution environment/Alternate JRE.

Comment: Then you need to download and install JRE and JDK.

Comment: I have another Eclipse installed, which works fine. This means I already have JRE and JDK installed, but I don't know how to bind them to the new Eclipse

Comment: Then did you try to edit `JRE System Library [jre1.8.0_31]`?

Comment: When I click on `Edit` it is set to `Workspace Default jre(jre1.8.0_31)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74399/discussion-between-naman-gala-and-dres).

Comment: Could you create some screen shots of your build path configuration and upload them somewhere? Impossible to diagnose without further information.

Comment: @dres what is the version of the JDK installed on your machine.?

Comment: With reference to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22617122/3898076), `Eclipse Indigo` might not support jre8!

Comment: @dres I think Naman has a good point; "Indigo" is like ages old. Unless you absolutely have to use an older version, it might be much easier to simply use the latest Eclipse version.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to know some stuffs about JAVA. Java uses a JVM (Java virtual machine) wich is the JDK and need to be installed on your computer.
The JDK makes the JVM run and the JRE allow you to compile etc java class. (No need for both, just install the JRE)
see [this](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/windows_offline_download.xml) page.

Then you'll have to configure a window GLOBAL VARIABLE. The JAVA_HOME var. 
"1-Right click My Computer and select Properties.
2-On the Advanced tab, select Environment Variables, and then edit JAVA_HOME to point to where the JDK software is located".

This way Eclipse will be able to find the installed JRE.

Finally, in eclipse, check that it know the JRE.

And that's it. There is a lot of info over the web about this for more details.

Comment: `Java uses a JVM (Java virtual machine) wich is the JDK` that is wrong

Comment: Of course it is not accurate enough, but for a beginner I believe it's a good   start to understand the use/need of the JVM