# java 8 support for Eclipse Indigo

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am using two different projects, one that uses java 7 and other java 8. I have Eclipse indigo, where i need to run these two projects on same.

i tried referring this link [How to add jdk8 in Eclipse Indigo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22574317/how-to-add-jdk8-in-eclipse-indigo) but this says i cant add these features to Eclipse Indigo.

How could i make Indigo support for java 8 and java 7 projects in same eclipse?. Which are jdk or jre i should install?

Comment: You download a newer version of eclipse; Indigo is really old. It simply doesn't support the newer features.

Comment: The question you link to is correct. You can't use Java 8 features in Indigo.